# Why is a remote server asking me to generate public/private SSH keys?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

Each time I access a specific remote server, it asks me to generate my public/private SSH keys, that it keeps on the machine.

Why is that? Don't I send my public key when I try to establish a connection with the server? Why is it asking me to generate them? What's the point if the server keeps the two keys locally?

Comment: When does it ask this? You do know that in SSH authentication is based on public key cryptography, and the session itself is encrypted using a shared key (symmetric)? During authentication, only the public key should reside on the server, not 'both'. Usually one puts this on the server prior to connecting, and the server expects it in the user's home directory on the server itself, usually in @HOME/.ssh/

Comment: And your ssh client expects the corresponding private key in your home directory on your client machine. Also in the same directory.

Comment: I know, that's my point. I thought I was missing something. Maybe since I'm logging on my account for the first time, SSL has to be configured. It has nothing to do with my connection.